# Using Mac to connect PlayStation 4 to VPN

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I am trying to set up my PlayStation to have VPN set up.

I have a Mac. I thought about buying a router, but it is too expensive, and I don't need a wireless setup. My Mac doesn't have LAN ports, so I cannot buy one Ethernet adapter as I need two lan ports to connect my Mac to Internet and the other to connect the Mac to PS4.

Is it possible to buy two ethernet adapters to make this work? Or is it better to just buy a cheap router that will support VPN?

Comment: macOS can run two logical networks over one connection so one adapter can serve many networks. What networking is present, we would need to know how you connect to the internet and how the ps4 connects to properly answer. Without a diagram or clear picture we are guessing what you have

Comment: I am trying to connect my Mac to a router( a cheap one that just comes from Internet service company) with an ethernet cable, and then connect my Mac with my PS4 with another ethernet cable. So, I need two physical lan ports for this to work.

Comment: Aah. You don’t have or want a hub or switch, got it. Thanks for clarifying that part of your VPN puzzle.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what a hub is or how I should handle this. All I want is a cheap way to equip my PS4 with VPN.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an inexpensive switch. Plug the router in to the switch and your PS4 and Mac into the switch.

- TP-Link 5 Port Fast Ethernet Switch | Desktop Ethernet Splitter | Ethernet Hub | Plug and Play | Fanless Quiet | Unmanaged (TL-SF1005D), White [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000FNFSPY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FNFSPY)

You could get faster networking in your building to go to gigabit speeds, but it’s unlikely your VPN or internet are faster than the switch I linked to. This won’t solve the VPN side, so ask that on a network site or once your physical network is working.

I would not have your Mac relay traffic when network gear is so much faster and power efficient.